# How to deal with AD when deploy Hyper-V cluster?

Tags: hyper-v, hypervisor

I try to plan Hyper-V cluster deployment over several host servers (10 or maybe 12; hosts are rented) placed in two separate datacenters. This will be Hyper-V Server 2019 Core hosts. The problem is, I don't know if I should rely on AD for host auth, and if not, then what's the best way to maintain the cluster.

The main idea was to create Hyper-V cluster that's not connected to office AD servers so even if office goes down for a long time services in datacenters should stay alive. I have no physical hosts in datacenters to serve AD only, all of these hosts are for Hyper-V, and I don't want to host AD controllers as VMs as it kills the whole idea.

Feel I miss something as I believe this is the question for each and every Hyper-V deplyment on a remote location, so pleace advice best way of how to work this out.

Thank you!

Comment: "Feel I miss something" - DOCUMENTATION? Clustering works even without domain now - workgroup - with nearly all features and since 2016. You must have overlooked that.

Comment: @TomTom I knew about domainless setup, but I deal with it back in Windows 2012 Hyper-V, so yes, I overlooked that in 2019. What's more interesting, I can't find best practice docs for "Put both AD DCs on Hyper-V and Hyper-V can be maintanced / start without AD and AD will be added at late stage" approach. Seems that it is against AD general approach, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> The main idea was to create Hyper-V cluster that's not connected to office AD
> servers so even if office goes down for a long time services in
> datacenters should stay alive.

What is the logic behind that give nthat "AD servers goes down" is a non issue if 2 of them live on the cluster, AND the cluster since 2019 can live and start without AD?

> and I don't want to host AD controllers as VMs as it kills the whole idea.

Nope, it does not. It follows best practices.

Comment: rent additional servers for the AD usually 4-8gb at least and 2-4 CPUs should be already overkill

Comment: Not really. One, every location should have AD to start with. Second, since - 2 years (2019 version) Clustering works perfectly without AD and ind mixed environments (some machines in AD, some of the servers in a workgroup).

Comment: This can be true but that's what I said, rent additional servers for the AD ;) if 2 location at least 1 one each site should be the standard ,better having 2 on each site. However in case you cluster such massive remind also how to backup the entire cluster